# How to Aggregate Items for a HeatMap or TreeMap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heatmap, treemap

I have a simple dataframe that looks like this.

```
Rating  Count
AA+ 0.06
AA  0
AA  0
AA+ 0.09
BBB 0.55
AA+ 0.04
AA  0
AA  0.11
B   0.54
A   0
BBB 0.5
```

I tried to plot it as both a HeatMap and a TreeMap.  I tested this simple code and got an error.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
sns.heatmap(df1, annot=True, fmt=".01", linewidths=.5, ax=ax)
```

Error: `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

I think the dataframe has to be pivoted, or somehow coerced into some other form.  What I would like to do is count the number of occurrences of 'AA+ 0.06' & 'AA+ 0.04', etc.  There are several of these patterns repeating.  There could be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc., counts or each.  How can I do that, and plot the results in a HeatMap or TreeMap?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
import squarify    # pip install squarify (algorithm for treemap)
import matplotlib

...etc.
squarify.plot(sizes=df_rtg['Count'], label=df_rtg['Rating'], alpha=.8 )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```